# Unable to Use Imported SPC Certification To Sign VBA File

Tags: ssl-certificate, internet-explorer, microsoft-excel, internet-explorer-11, mmc

I have a tricky issue, I'm trying to install a certificate to sign a VBA file. I've purchased a third party certificate and followed the [instructions here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73b68f1a-9361-497e-aba8-ec8b09e0691f/how-to-install-a-code-signing-certificate-for-excel-vba-macros?forum=exceldev) to install it and sign my VBA file with it. However, I'm getting the following error when I try to use my certificate:

> [No usable signing certificates](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-i-installed-digital-signing-certificate-but/231529b1-8099-4c7b-9bb6-2c36aeba00a4)

[image]

(I believe) This is because, even though I've been able to install my new certificate through MMC in both my user account and local computer under the "Personal" folder, I haven't yet been able to install my certificate through IE.

When I attempt to install my new certificate (SPC file) in IE, I'm able to select it in the Import Wizard, and specify all settings correctly, however when I finish the wizard:

[image]

And I receive the "Success" message, the certificates are not imported, in fact I see no change in the "Personal" screen. This is in stark contrast to the behavior that I see in MMC, where I repeat the same steps and after completing the wizard, the two certificates in my SPC are installed without issue.

I've tried restarting, importing the certificates basically everywhere in MMC, but I cannot get these certificates to install in IE and consequentially I cannot sign my VBA files.

## Update 1

I've got my certificate to show up under "Other People" now, can't remove it or move it though, and I still get the same error in VBA when trying to sign my file with it, does my cert need to be in the "Personal" folder, or can one sign a VBA file with a cert in the "Other People" folder?

I wonder what criteria excel uses to determine if a particular cert is one that can be used to sign a file. So far I have not found any documentation on this. I have found a old post on [conflicting versions](https://serverfault.com/a/557759/422333). That could be the issue I suppose, but I'm not sure what aspect or version excel is looking for...

## Update 2

I was issued a SPC file, (hypothesis) I believe I need to sign the file with [the following instructions](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/windows-install-codedriver-signing-certificate-and-create-pfx-file-2698) before I can use it. [That](https://superuser.com/questions/1098614/how-can-i-export-a-certificate-from-mmc-as-a-pfx-file), is considerably harder than it first seems. Seems my files "private key" is marked as non-exportable:

> Export-PfxCertificate : Cannot export non-exportable private key.

I wonder why my third party cert authority provided me with a cert formatted in this manner. Seems I'm not the only one confused my this [cert business either](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1032132-cant-digitally-sign-excel-2013-a.html). [Lots of discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/vba-i-installed-digital-signing-certificate-but/231529b1-8099-4c7b-9bb6-2c36aeba00a4?page=2) on the internet about this sort of thing, just not allot of particularity useful instructions on how to do it. I really hope I don't have to [proceed down this path.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914882/how-to-export-non-exportable-private-key-from-store)

Answer (score 0):

I reran through the [entire process](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/rekey-my-certificate-4976), including regenerating my CSR file with the ["Marked private key exportable"](https://sg.godaddy.com/help/windows-generate-csr-for-code-or-driver-signing-certificate-7282), for some reason the second time around the key on my newly provided cert was now marked exportable, I was able to export it into a PFX, install that, and then sign my VBA file without issue.